# MEF : How can I import a class which has a constructor marked with the ImportingConstructorFlag

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, mef

My question title sounds a little bit difficult - sorry. I'm new in MEF :-).

My scenario:

```
public class MainClass
{
  [ImportMany(typeof(ITest))]
  private List<ITest> Tests { get; set; }

  public MainClass()
  {
    Init();
  }

  private void Init()
  {
     DirectoryCatalog catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(@"./");
     CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
     container.ComposeParts(this);
  }
}



[Export("BirthdayJob")]
[Export(typeof(ITest))]
public partial class BirthdayTest : ITest
{
  [ImportingConstructor]
  public BirthdayUserControl(IParameter parameter)
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     this.Parameter = jobParameter;
  }

   public IParameter Parameter { get; set; }
}

[Export(typeof(IParameter))]
[Export("BirthdayParameter")]
public class BirthdayJobParameter : IParameter
{
   public override string ToString()
   {
       return "Birthday Remember";
   }
}


public interface IParameter : IMefInterface
{

}

public interface IMefInterface
{

}
```

In the generic list of test, I should have all possible ITest objects with the associated IParameter object. Unfortunately, there aren't any items in the generic list.

Can you help? What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Regards, pro

//Edit

So I have a compilable Class for my problem :

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;

namespace ObjectContracts
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var container = new CompositionContainer(new TypeCatalog(typeof (IFoo), typeof (Bar), typeof(Foo)));
            var bar = container.GetExportedValue<Bar>();
            Console.WriteLine(bar.Foo.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

    }

    [InheritedExport]
    public interface IFoo
    {
        string Message { get; set; }
    }

    [Export]
    public class Bar
    {
        [ImportingConstructor]
        public Bar([Import("Foo")]IFoo foo)
        {
            this.Foo = foo;
        }

        public IFoo Foo { get; set;}
    }

    [Export("Foo")]
    public class Foo : IFoo
    {
        public Foo()
        {
            Message = ":-)";
        }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What do I do wrong? Please help me :-)

Regards, patrick

Comment: What do you get? If anything.... Do you know the MEFX Composition Analysis Tool (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff576068.aspx) which can help you troubleshoot such cases?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But all parts are correct loaded. Only the property won't be injected correctly...:-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that if you use a contract (in your case "BirthdayJob") in your export, you need to specify that in your import as well. Like so:

```
[Export("BirthdayJob",typeof(ITest))]
public partial class BirthdayTest : ITest
{
  // class definition
}
```

And your import:

```
public class MainClass
{
  [ImportMany("BirthdayJob",typeof(ITest))]
  private List<ITest> Tests { get; set; }

  // class definition
}
```

The great thing about contracts is that they allow you to group instances of certain objects of a specific type and filter out any unwanted instances of objects of a specific type.

MEF is the coolest!

```
[Export("PeopleLivingInEdmontonAlbertaCanada",typeof(IPerson))]
public Person KevinParkinson { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking a wild guess, it is possibly the working directory of your `DirectoryCatalog` (depending on how you run the app.)

To verify that this is the problem, replace:

```
DirectoryCatalog catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(@"./");
```

With either:

```
DirectoryCatalog catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(@"<full path to directory>");
```

or:

```
AssemblyCatalog catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(BirthdayTest).Assembly);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the current directory (@"./") is right. I've verified that with the debugger. After the ComposeParts() call,all assemblies are correct loaded and all parts are corrected listed...

Comment: You're welcome - I'm out of ideas though. If you can post a complete (compilable) example I can take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution.  In the export class of the foo class should be a reference of the derived interface. The constructor which have the importingconstructor flag should have also a reference to the interface.

```
 [Export]
    public class Bar
    {
        [ImportingConstructor]
        public Bar([Import("Foo", typeof(IFoo))]IFoo foo)
        //public Bar([Import(typeof(IFoo))]IFoo foo)
        {
            this.Foo = foo;
        }

        public IFoo Foo { get; set;}
    }

    [Export("Foo", typeof(IFoo))]
    public class Foo : IFoo
    {
        public Foo()
        {
            Message = ":-)";
        }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you exporting IParameter anywhere?  In the code you posted, you are not, and this is why the Birthday test isn't being picked up.

Comment: Yes he is ! scroll down the code all the way - the class `BirthdayJobParameter` clearly exports `IParameter`

Comment: @marc_s Oops, I must have missed the scroll bar! :)